# How i can send automatic email when i confirm a form request on Odoo 8?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

i'm a new Odoo developer and i need to send automatic email when i confirm a form request, and i can input manually sender and receiver the email.
Any one have a sample, tutorial or anyone can help me, i dont know the steps or configure of mail server because i use localhost, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting-> Technical setting-> Email-> Outgoing Mail Servers
Set SMTP server, SMTP port other credentials

eg:
SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP port: 587
connection security: TLS(STARTTLS)

Once done, Test the connection is setup properly or not by clicking Test connection button.

You can send mail by calling send_mail()

Comment: am i must use port 587 ?
i was input smtp server, and i got Odoo warning
 Connection Test Failed!
Here is what we got instead:
-2
Name or service not known

Comment: You have to use SMTP port of domain provider.                                            For eg                                                                                                      Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587
Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465

Comment: i was set SMTP port TLS/SSL but still get same error.
"Connection Test Failed! Here is what we got instead: -2 Name or service not known"

Comment: please check 2 step verification is not ON in gmail, if its ON then provide application specific password.If still not working, attach snap of it.

Comment: thanks sir, the problem was on my gmail, its not allow login from another application. thanks